# How do I execute a script on a LTSP-Thin Client after boot?

Tags: boot, scripts, ltsp, ltsp-client

**What is the best way to execute a script after boot/reboot on a specific thin-client in an LTSP enviroment?**

I want to run a script after boot to execute `ltsp-localapps foo` , but only on one client. Normally I would use `/etc/rc.local` - but in LTSP this would affect all clients using this image.

My best idea, so far, is to use the lts.conf parameter:

```
CRONTAB_01..CRONTAB_10
           string, default unset
           A crontab line to add for a thin client.
```

with
  `@reboot`        *Run once, at startup.*

but as `man 5 crontab` states

```
   Please  note  that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is the time
   when the cron(8) daemon startup.  In particular, it may be before  some
   system  daemons, or other facilities, were startup.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer on [irc.ltsp.org, see 14:25 to 14:35](http://irclogs.ltsp.org/?d=2017-05-24).

There is a lts.conf parameter called  RCFILE_01...RCFILE_10 which allows to run scripts as a system services on startup:

```
RCFILE_01...RCFILE_10
       string, default unset
       Commands to be executed from /etc/rc.local when the client boots
```

Quote from the chat's original poster at position 14:35 hours:

> ...rcfile is in the chroot, and the path is relative ... for example file is
>   in /opt/ltsp/(arch)/etc/rc.local/a_filename and in lts.conf it is
>   RCFILE_01="/etc/rc.local/a_filename"